# Unable to deploy the Windows Azure WebJob with updated dll's

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am deploying the windows Azure Web Job using Visual Studio 2013. When i change the code an publish the webjob, its not taking the latest dll's referred in the Web Job. Please let me know how to publish the Web Jo with the updated DLL's

Comment: Could you specify the steps you follow to deploy the webjob? Have you tried restarting the app service?